# Disable 'Antivirus not installed' nag

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus

How do I disable the nag balloon that comes up on the task bar from time to time?

Comment: Install some anti-virus software?

Comment: What if you don't fancy the constant performance overhead for something unlikely to ever help you?

Comment: Just use an anti-virus product that doesn't eat up that much performance. Or set up your anti-virus product to not eat up that much performance...

Comment: There is no AV product that doesn't eat up performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Action center, change action center settings.

[image]

There you can turn messages on or off.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Go to **Control Panel** > **System and Security** > **Windows Solution Center**

[image]

Under **Security** > **Virus protection (Important)** click **Turn off messages like this**.

Answer (score 4):

Install an anti-virus program.

Comment: This would be the best solution in my opinion. :-)

Comment: giving in to the nagging makes the warning go away alright, but it does not 'disable' it. :)

Comment: @Molly: Which is why I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the 'Windows Security Center' service, in services.msc